# Hosting two websites in one domain using nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have an angularjs website (with a nodejs server.js file that hosts it on port 8100). I use Nginx to reverse proxy into that port.

I would like users who come to a separate path (say www.example.com/location1) to go to a completely different website (a different AngularJS folder with a different server.js file).

The Node.js files run on my server.  But the front end throws an injection error when I try to run the two websites. Is it even possible to do this?

FYI: When I run a single website on the server, it works... but it doesn't work when I run both.

Edit: both the websites work on my localhost perfectly.

My Nginx sites-available/default file

```
server {
...

location / {
proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8100;
proxy_redirect    off;
proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP    $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}


location /location1/ {
proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_redirect    off;
proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP    $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

My Server.js files (more or less the same for both files):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'pw')));
app.all('*',function(req,res,next){
res.sendFile('pw/index.html',{root:__dirname});
});

app.listen(8100); //This will be 8080 for the other server.js file (which has been renamed something else
```

Comment: Look like you have to move the /location1/ block to front of / block

Comment: Oh! Does that matter in nginx?

Comment: I guess that :D

Comment: apologies for the delay...but it didn't work